# Bootstrap: Textarea height shrinked when I apply Bootstrap style to it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I have a textarea with its height attribute set to 100% in CSS. It looks like this:
[image: original height]

When I apply bootstrap style(adding 'form-control' class to it), I looks like this:
[image: After I apply 'form-control' class]

After Inspecting the element. I found that bootstrap override its height value to be "auto". The CSS looks like this:

```
textarea.form-control{
    height: auto;
}
```

But even if I changed the height in above code to

```
textarea.form-control {
    height:100%
}
```

It still looked like this:
[image]

Notice the height still shrinked a little, comparing to the original one.

How can I set its height to what it original was(like in the first picture) and still apply Bootstrap style to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try this, hope this will works for you.

```
textarea.form-control {
    height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I just put the "!important" in my original CSS class selector and it overrides the "auto" value from bootstrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To make the height of the `textarea 100%`,
Better use the the below css style:

```
textarea.form-control {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

This style will overwrite the style of `.form-control` class of bootstrap.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You could set a fixed height on its parent.

```
<div class="form-group" style="height:100px;">
  <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
  <button class="btn">Create tweet</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean, style="height:100px";